# Can't parse longitude and latitude BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

If i use this

```
 'latitude': item.find('div', class_='data-shop-latitude').get_text(),
 'longitude': item.find('div', class_='data-shop-longitude').get_text(),
```

I get

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

If i use that

```
'latitude': item.find('div', class_='data-shop-latitude'),
'longitude': item.find('div', class_='data-shop-longitude'),
```

I get

> 'latitude': None, 'longitude': None,

How i can get this:

> 'latitude': 52.42065, 'longitude': 37.59659,

Comment: Please, provide a Minimal Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Seems like you parsing the webpage wrong as bs4 cannot find tags you are talking about. Can you provide the HTML code / URL or input data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` takes a kwarg called `attrs` that you should use.

Once you've got the shops with `soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'shop-list-item'})`, all you need to do is get the value of the different attributes you're interested in using the `get` method on the `div` element (whose type is `bs4.element.Tag`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(r'https://www.mebelshara.ru/contacts')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

shops = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'shop-list-item'})
for shop in shops:
    print(shop.get('data-shop-name'))
    print(shop.get('data-shop-latitude'))
    print(shop.get('data-shop-longitude'))
    print()
```

Output:

```
ТЦ Европа
50.59084
36.59734

ТЦ Атлас
50.58516
36.565457

ТЦ РИО
50.64208
36.572086

[...]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: If that's still the case, it means within the `item` element, there is no `div` element with its `class` attribute set to `data-shop-latitude` or `data-shop-latitude`. If you want more help, you'll need to post the html/url, as suggested by *Igor Hwang*.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eJqgkZH2 — html
>     items = soup.find_all('div', class_='shop-list-item')
url — https://www.mebelshara.ru/contacts

Comment: I've updated my answer. You've [pretty much, with your code corrected] already got the `div` elements you want. You just need to read the attributes using the `get` method.